# iterator.groupby() cannot generate the correct result

Tags: python, iterator

Code:

```
import itertools
first_letter = lambda x: x[0]
names = ['Alan', 'Adam', 'Wes', 'Albert', 'Steven']
for letter, name in itertools.groupby(names, first_letter):
    print(letter, list(name))
```

Output:

```
A ['Alan', 'Adam']
W ['Wes']
A ['Albert']
S ['Steven']
```

I want to group by the first element, but it seems not work well, what's wrong here?

Comment: The input is not sorted, iterators always process sequentially

Comment: what do you mean? the input has to be well sorted? but I just want to groupby

Comment: I have hopefully answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you would expect form any function in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) operates on sequences of elements that share a common key. You have to remember that an iterator can be any source of sequential data, possibly one that doesn't store is own elements as a list does.

What this means is that if the data is not already grouped within the iterator, `groupby` won't work the way you expect.  Put it another way, `groupby` starts another group whenever the key changes, regardless of whether the key has already appeared in the sequence or not.

Probably the easiest way to pre-group the data in your case is to sort it. Lists can be sorted in-place:

```
names=['Alan','Adam','Wes','Albert','Steven']
names.sort()
for letter, name in itertools.groupby(names, first_letter):
    print( letter, list(name))
```

A similar result could be obtained by distributing your list into a dictionary. I use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) below because it makes adding new elements easier. You could use a regular dictionary just as easily:

```
grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name in names:
    grouped[name[0]].append(name)

for letter, group in grouped.items():
    print(letter, group)
```

In either case, the point is that you can't expect `groupby` to do exactly what you want with the order of elements in your raw data.